# download csv in android

Tags: android

im trying to download a csv file and then need to extract information from it...
i tried the following code...

```
URL url=new URL("http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=INFY.BO&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgv&e=.csv");
HttpURLConnection c=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
c.setRequestMethod("GET");
c.connect();
InputStream is = c.getInputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) 
{
sb.append(buffer);
}
System.out.println("\n\n\nSTRING >>>>>>>>>>>>> "+sb+"\n\n\n");
```

Now this always displays an error saying it closed unexpectedly.

the logcat - [link](http://dos_killer.byethost7.com/images/Document.rtf)

Comment: What does the error say in the logcat? Please provide this by editing your answer and giving us the full stack trace.

Comment: the logcat - [link](http://dos_killer.byethost7.com/images/Document.rtf)

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure `sb` is constructed
- Add permission `android.permission.INTERNET`
- Use `BufferedReader` to read from a character stream. (`sb` isn't used here)

.

```
InputStream is = c.getInputStream();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
String line = null;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    Log.i("msg", new String(line));
}
```